# what about enahanced functionality to allow answers to have richer educational content?

Tags: feature-request

I just got a nice answer to [one of my questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52135/confusion-about-time-shift-in-special-relativity/52147#52147), and it occurs to me that it might be awesome if, when answering a question, someone could build simple animations.  I've never seen anything like this before and it would tend to increase the quality of experience for both askers and answerers...

I'd be willing to work on something like that, sort of like a mini Flash Editor but only in JavaScript, **if** it doesn't already exist for free that is (hard to have an original thought in this world), but the question is a) do others think its a good idea b) would something like that have a chance of going live.

I could work on something like this for fun obviously, but it would be more motivating if I thought the result might get deployed on a site like this....

Comment: Couldn't this be achieved by just putting an animated gif?

Comment: You may be interested in http://stackapps.com/ if you haven't already seen it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be useful, but I have my doubts that it would be deployed here because the SE team has been quite reluctant to add heavy Javascript dependencies. We already have one on the site, namely MathJax, so I don't think they would put in another. But I couldn't say for sure.

Honestly, the way to get people talking about doing that would be to actually make it, and once you have a working demonstration, then ask whether it could be added to the site.

Comment: thanks for the helpful feedback